# How can I execute code located on a GitHub repo at specific intervals?

Tags: github, github-pages, github-api

I have a GitHub pages site that needs to receive updates at unknown intervals throughout the day.

It takes about 20-30 seconds for updates to `index.md` to go live.

I realized that if multiple updates occur in close succession to one another before the website has a chance to refresh, only the last update will appear.

My idea was to queue updates to `index.md` in `append.md` and then use the GitHub API to push the contents of `append.md` to `index.md` every minute. This drastically reduces the amount of time in which an update can be missed, from 30 seconds to only about half a second or so.

Is it possible to achieve this?

The code would need to be located and executed from the repository itself, as I have no way of hosting it permanently on a server.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that with a GitHub Pages site you have no backend as such.  There is no server.

You are limited to what you can do with text, static images and JavaScript.